# Setup two page site using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to setup a really simple two page layout.

Here is my main entry page:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
       <Route path="/" component={HomeTheme} />
       <Route path="blog" component={BlogTheme} />
    </Router>
      ,rootElement
);
```

I would like to render each route with a different layout, as below:

```
//Main Layout     
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <MainNavigation />
            <AboutPage />
            <SkillsSection />
            <ExperienceSection />
            <Blog content={this.state.text} />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}


//Blog Layout     
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BlogHeader />
            <MainNavigation />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Problem I have is the layout always defaults to the `HomeTheme`, how can i use a different component for each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{this.props.children}` inside your main component to render all routes.

Your Router should be something like this :

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="blog" component={Blog}/>
    <Route path="registration" component={Registration} />
</Route>
```

Inside your App you should have something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
         return {this.props.children};
    }
}
```

And inside index route, in this case HomePage you should have a nav to navigate between routes.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
class HomePage extends Component {
   render() {
     return (<ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="blog">Blog</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="registration">Registration</Link></li>
             </ul>)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.